# Date.toLocaleString() broken in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Date.toLocaleString() returns this in Chrome:

- Mon Jan 18 2010 16:47:42 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)

In firefox, it's this:

- Monday, 18 January 2010 4:47:42 PM

Browser version doesn't seem to matter.  Anyone have a suggestion on this one?

Comment: What *exactly* seems to be the problem?

Comment: All the `Date.prototype.to[...]String` methods are implementation-dependent (with the exception of the ECMAScript 5 `toISOString`)

Comment: shylent, you don't see a difference between those results? :)  In chrome, all my date fields take 2 lines because they're so much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date.toLoacaleString is an issue on chrome:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29779&q=tolocalestring&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS

Comment: That's not the issue.  That ticket implies that a localization was missing and the string was not provided in the expected language.

Answer (score 0):

As CMS answered above, these methods can return pretty much anything they want, hopefully in a representation that is readable to someone in that locale (language + cultural conventions)  To obtain a particular formatting of a Date, you need to use a library like DateJS or Dojo.