# js Date toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, date

I use the 3 browsers to output this result.

Chrome:

```
new Date().toLocaleString()
> "Sun Sep 04 2011 21:40:04 GMT+0800 (HKT)"
```

Safari:

```
new Date().toLocaleString()
> "2011年9月4日 下午09时54分51秒格林尼治标准时间+0800"
```

FF:

```
new Date().toLocaleString()
> "Sun Sep 4 21:46:03 2011"
```

why not the same output result? timezoom?

Comment: What is the output in each browser?

Comment: chrome: 
new Date().toLocaleString()
"Sun Sep 04 2011 21:40:04 GMT+0800 (HKT)"
safari: 
>>> new Date().toLocaleString()
"2011年9月4日 下午09时54分51秒格林尼治标准时间+0800"
FF:
>>> new Date().toLocaleString()
"Sun Sep 4 21:46:03 2011"

Comment: I hesitated calling this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115725/date-tolocalestring-broken-in-chrome but this is the real question, the other one is only a good question by luck!

Comment: Try to use localization parameter. Example: `new Date().toLocaleString("en-us")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the configuration of the computer, the user's preferred date format, obviously the user's locale, and how the browser determines this.

You should really prefer using a proper date library such as [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) for formatting.

See their [`Date.toString()`](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString) and [`format specifiers`](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers).

Comment: looks like there might be more to it than user settings, checkout that nasty chrome bug!

Comment: Just wanted to throw out that http://momentjs.com/ is a really good library for this - Datejs looks like it is not maintained.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in webkit, actually; in particular in Chrome but Safari is indeed affected too: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=3607

toLocaleString() does not translate to the locale!

The worst is, it's closed as WontFix. How is that possible? We should try and re-open it. The conclusion on the bug is that somewhen a new [javascript globalization apis](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=globalization%3aglobalization) (that is well explained [here](http://norbertlindenberg.com/2011/11/ecmascript-globalization-api/index.html)) will appear. That doesn't sound like a solution to me!

In any case, if possible, follow @arnaud576875 suggestion to use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) which is old but still very good.

Comment: The Chrome bug 3607 is marked Fixed now, but it is not fixed. I added comment #28 there. Basically, it gives an American format time on my system, where I have set a Slovenian locale. Other browsers give correct localized string.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

And this example:

```js
var event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

// British English uses day-month-year order and 24-hour time without AM/PM
console.log(event.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' }));
// expected output: 20/12/2012, 03:00:00

// Korean uses year-month-day order and 12-hour time with AM/PM
console.log(event.toLocaleString('ko-KR', { timeZone: 'UTC' }));
// expected output: 2012. 12. 20. 오전 3:00:00
```